# filter out numbers from SQL statement in groovy controller code and display just alplhabetic characyers in gsp view

Tags: java, grails, groovy, gsp

In my groovy service class , I have a SQL statement which sometimes returns numbers with concepts for ex: `01 John`, `02 Smith`. How can I filter only John, Smith  and not include numbers. I want to show in my gsp view only John , Smith and not the number tags before them?

In the groovy Controller Code I call the function:

```
def wiki =
{
    def currentNode = params.nodePath
    def conceptName = nodeService.retrieveConceptName (currentNode);
    render (template:'wiki', model:[conceptName : conceptName])
}
```

In the service class I define the function retrieveConceptName:

```
def retrieveConceptName(currentNode)  
{  
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource);  
    def row= sql.firstRow(" SELECT cname FROM Person WHERE FULLNAME= ?",[currentNode]);  
    return row;  
}
```

.gsp view:(starting lines)

```
<span class="metaDataDialog nodePathTitle">${conceptName.cname}</span>
```

Comment: So you have numbers in your cname field? Maybe sanitise your data?

Comment: How to sanitize the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regex](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions) to sanitise your data. So regex will remove all numbers and blanks from the name. In your case you can use `.replaceAll(/[0-9 ]/, "")`, which will replace all the numbers and blanks from your names. Try this code:

```
def wiki =
{
    def currentNode = params.nodePath
    def conceptName = nodeService.retrieveConceptName(currentNode)
    conceptName.cname = conceptName.cname.replaceAll(/[0-9 ]/, "")
    render (template:'wiki', model:[conceptName : conceptName])
}
```

Comment: But it dint work. It does not recognize the replaceAll function?

Comment: It should be: conceptName.cname = conceptName.cname.replaceAll(/[0-9 ]/, "")

Comment: Hey Suppose if I have my cname values as 01 John1Smith, I want to only replace starting 01 and retain John1Smith. How can I retain middle 1(number) in it? output : John1Smith